# Redirect Soap request with apache

Tags: php, apache, redirect, soap, soapui

Excuse my for my English, I’m French.

I have a question about soap request redirection with apache (on wampserver).

I have one file `server.php` on `localhost:3511`

**vhost :**

```
<VirtualHost *:3511>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/test/server.php"
ServerName test.local
</VirtualHost>
```

**server.php :**

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
require_once('Test.php');

$wsdl = "CurrencyConvertor.asmx.wsdl";
$server = new SoapServer($wsdl);
$server->setClass("Test");
$server->handle();
?>
```

My class **Test.php :**

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public function ConversionRate($p_conversion_rate_request)
    {   

        return array('ConversionRateResult' => 0);
    }
}
```

With SoapUi, I have this result when I call

```
http://localhost:3511


<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:ConversionRateResponse>
         <ns1:ConversionRateResult>0</ns1:ConversionRateResult>
      </ns1:ConversionRateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So it works!

Now I want to redirect request to

```
http://localhost/test2/server.php
```

when soapui call localhost:3511.
I have the same project in `localhost/test2/` but `ConversionRateResult` returns `1` instead of `0`.

I have made an htaccess in `localhost/test/` with this code :

```
Redirect / http://localhost/test2/server.php
```

When I test this url `localhost:3511` in a web browser, `test2/server.php` is called. It works but when I call `localhost:3511` with SoapUi, nothing was returned.

Can you explain me what’s wrong with my htaccess?
May be I must add something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Proxy flag [P]:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  /  http://localhost/test2/server.php  [NC, P]
```

mod_proxy:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.htm

flag:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html